# Adding a new homepage to Drupal

Tags: php, css, drupal, drupal-7

I'm just getting started with Drupal and have added my preffered modules. I have also added my front-end framework module - which is Foundation Zurb. Now I'd like to change the default blog-like structure of the site and would like to add a custom developed homepage. Been trying to put my head around this for over 3 days with no success. I followed the direction on the Drupal docs - which is a bit confusing and rigid but something I dont grasp is does the page--front.tpl.php actually end up being the home page? Also where would I put my css and other js scripts?

If this is the case then what would I need to do to add a navigation to this homepage which would then provide links to my site? Some mind opening guidance is welcome

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'Homepage'? The landing page of your site?

Comment: Yes a landing page. That's what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set any node in any content type to be the home page. So first create your content type, then node in that type.

Then go to Confugration -> System -> Site information in admin menu and there you have Front page section. Add your page path to "Default front page" field and that's it - your page will become new home page.

Comment: Okay so after I have done it from the configuration end, can I like customize the newly created page on a text editor ?

Comment: Yes, if your page is in i.e. "home" (it's machine name) content type you can create node--home.tpl.php file to style your page. Crete template file, clear the cache and drupal will start using it.

Comment: Read/watch some theming tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. Which directory would I place the node--home.tpl.php file? In my theme folder or?

Comment: /site/all/themes/your_theme_name/templates

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable the default view "Frontpage" that has a path /frontpage. In this you can customize the sorting and filtering of what is being shown. Then visit the "Site information" page and set "/frontpage" as your default frontpage.